# Xamarin Forms - Get position of item selected in Listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im having a bit of trouble trying to get the position of an item in a ListView when its tapped.

Heres my code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Results();
}

async void Results()
{
    var service = new RestService();
    response = await service.GetEventItemsAsync();

    Debug.WriteLine("Found: " + response.Count + " events");

    listView.ItemsSource = response;

    listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        // Get position of item tapped 
    };
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLVED**

Had to change *ItemTapped* to *ItemSelected*

Then inside the *ItemSelected* I just added in this line:

```
var i = (listView.ItemsSource as List<EventItems>).IndexOf(e.SelectedItem as EventItems);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In SelectedItem event try this:

```
var index = (myListView.ItemsSource as List<MyObject>).IndexOf (e.SelectedItem as MyObject);
```

Comment: Sorry for this, but what would be MyObject?

Comment: How to do that if `ItemsSource` is of type `ObservableCollection<ObservableGroupCollection<string, MyObject>>`?

Comment: WORKING FOR ME.. WITH YOUR ANSWER & CHANGE THE ItemTapped  TO ItemSelected.. THANKS FOR ASKER & ANSWERER. @testing I use the code like this 
**myObjectCollection.IndexOf(e.SelectedItem as MyObject);** this code working for me..

Comment: Variation: var index = (myListView.ItemsSource as IList).IndexOf (e.SelectedItem);

Answer (score 0):

While adding items in listView , you can set styleId of that item .
in ItemTapped body you will have access to that item thereby access to styleId of that item .