# Xamarin Forms - How to get the index number from ListView SelectedItem

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, int, selecteditem

I am completely stuck on this.
I have a ListView defined in XAML code, but I need to find out what the `int` of the selected item I am tapping.

My listview is called `PeopleList`
When I tap on a cell I need to get the index number of that cell.

So I can do `PeopleList.SelectedItem` but this returns an object - not an int.

I have tried parsing it and converting and everything that makes logically sense to me.

Can someone please tell me how to get the int for the selectedItem?

Comment: What type of collection is behind it? Are you using databinding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593735/xamarin-forms-get-position-of-item-selected-in-listview this answers your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Forms - Get position of item selected in Listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593735/xamarin-forms-get-position-of-item-selected-in-listview)

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate reference. Someone else was kind enough to give me the answer below, which was the same solution. I obviously missed that in my searches.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the event handler for your `ItemTapped` event, do the following:

```
private void Handle_ItemTapped (object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var index = (myListView.ItemsSource as List<Person>).IndexOf (e.SelectedItem as Person);
}
```

Make sure the type of the collection is right.
This isn't the most elegant way, but it works.

Comment: Thank you for this - it works nicely :-) I had had the logic at one stage but missed the itemsSource as List<Person>.

Do you know what would be the reason why you have to specify what your item source is, even though you are linking the event to the list specifically?

Comment: But What if I have Duplicate element in my List... In that scenario how to get the correct index???

Answer (score 0):

I think you can search the SelectedItem in your List.

For Example, in your ViewModel you have an `ObservableCollection` (MyList for example).

You have binded (in Xaml) this Collection to your `PeopleList`

then you can do something like

```
int myindex = MyList.IndexOf(SelectedItem);
```

for example

```
    ObservableCollection<string> l = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    l.Add("AAA");
    l.Add("BBB");
    l.Add("CCC");
    int idx = l.IndexOf("BBB");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("idx = " + idx.ToString());
```

Comment: When I do that it returns -1
_person is my ObservableCollection - 
`int myindex = _person.IndexOf(PeopleList.SelectedItem as Person);
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"####### - {myindex}");`

Comment: are you sure you have not modified your collection? Have you tried with Debug? You can also use a foreach... take a look if SelectedItem is present in _person with a foreach

Answer (score 0):

You listview is lstInfo uses ItemSelected for select the listview

```
lstInfo.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    //get all data in you row in the listview "lstinfo"
                    //And MFoto is you Model {get; set}
                    var item = e.SelectedItem as MFoto;

                    //View id for you listview
                    DisplayAlert("Data", item.Id, "OK");

                };
```