# Xamarin ListView SelectedIndex with duplicates in list

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I have been scouring SO and xamarin forums for a couple hours now and have yet to find a solution that works for me. I'm working on a xamarin app that uses a listview which contains a list of usernames. When I click on the user, I want a map to pan to that users location. No problem, except I can't figure out how to get the index of the user from the listview when there are duplicates in the list.

I've attempted to use this:

```
var index = usersInGroup.IndexOf(MyListView.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

but this finds the first index in my list and doesn't give accurate results. 
I've also attempted to implement solutions found here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41504/get-position-and-item-number-of-list-item, and here [Xamarin Forms - Get position of item selected in Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593735/xamarin-forms-get-position-of-item-selected-in-listview), as well as few other sources. Any help is much appreciated. Below is the code that I currently have for my listview. Just an FYI, this is my first xamarin project, and I am still figuring it out!

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    RowHeight="55"
    IsVisible="True"
    x:FieldModifier="public"                    
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
      Grid.Row="3"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
      BackgroundColor="White">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="Black" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C#:

```
public GroupPage ()
{
    MyListView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>(getUsers());
    MyListView.ItemSelected += listMemberSelected;
}

private void listMemberSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Doesn't work correctly when list contains duplicates
    var index = usersInGroup.IndexOf(MyListView.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

If I've left out any details you find important, please let me know.

Comment: Why do you have duplicates in the list? I'd see about removing dupes.

Comment: @RyanWilson  The list is populated by usernames which are not unique. Users are able to add whatever name they want. I've considered that solution, but it would mean restructuring the DB

Comment: you don't have to restructure your DB, just change your query which returns the Users to select only DISTINCT Names

Comment: why can't you just use SelectedItem?  Why do you have to have the index?

Comment: @RyanWilson If I were to do it that way I would be missing users from my list/map that share the same username

Comment: Why would you have multiple users with the same username, that makes no sense.

Comment: @Jason SelectedItem returns the username, but I need to loop through a list of coordinates that are associated with that user. So I need the index of that user so I can match it to index of the list that contains their coordinates. If that makes sense

Comment: instead of ObservableCollection<string>, use ObservableCollection<User> as your ItemSource, that will return the selected User object, not just the name

Comment: @RyanWilson There are plenty of examples of applications that don't require unique usernames. I believe there are also plenty of scenarios where getting the selected index of the listview is important. I know I can do this in a regular windows form app using int index = listView.FocusedItem.Index; I'm just asking for a similar solution here, if that's possible

Comment: @Jason Thank you. I will try to give that a shot. I don't currently have a user class but I will work on implementing one now

Comment: @JeremyRing so how is the user going to be able to select the correct person if it displays the same username for two different people?

Answer (score 0):

Less than ideal, but I ended up going with a grid whose controls are generated dynamically at runtime. I put the whole thing in a scrollview to get the scroll similar to listview and the usernames are in buttons that fill the row and are styled to match the grid.

XAML

```
            <ScrollView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid x:Name="grdMembersGrid" RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
```

C#:

Add whatever to the grid

```
                MyButton groupMembers = new MyButton();

            //Change text to username
            groupMembers.Text = usersInGroup[i];
            groupMembers.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            groupMembers.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            groupMembers.TextColor = Color.Black;
            groupMembers.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            groupMembers.Clicked += GroupMembers_Clicked;

            grdMembersGrid.Children.Add(groupMembers, 0, userRowIndex);
```

To get the row on the button click event:

```
        var row = (int)((BindableObject)sender).GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
```